# Kotlin- Coroutines and ThreadLocal in the same project: best practices question

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm converting a large project (Spring boot, GraphQL server) to coroutines.

Since this is a large project, I'm not converting it all at once and need to work in parallel with `ThreadLocal` and `CoroutineContext` for interop.

We currently have a class that wraps `ThreadLocal` manipulation, my plan is to create an equivalent for `CoroutineContext` and to use [ThreadContextElement](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-thread-context-element/) as well as [asContextElement](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/-coroutine-context/) to ensure the non-coroutine and the coroutine parts of my code interop properly.

**Questions:**

- Are there better alternatives to implement such interop?
- Are there good examples of such a mix I can use as good reference?
- Are there any pitfalls I should be aware of?

Thanks!